# padding image array with gray background

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am comparing thumbnail images by showing them side by side using `Image.fromarray(np.haystack(<list of image array>).show()`. The problem is that the image arrays have different sizes. My solution is to pad the array with a background gray color (200, 200, 200) and make all arrays equal size 200x200.

My question does numpy have a more direct way of doing this?

My solution:

```
def pad_with_gray_backgound(_array, size):
    array_padded = np.ones((size, size, 3), dtype=np.uint8)*200

    for i in range(array_padded.shape[0]):
        for j in range(array_padded.shape[1]):
            try:
                array_padded[i, j] = _array[i, j]
            except IndexError:
                pass

    return array_padded
```

and to call this function

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image_arrays = []
for pic in pic_selection:
    pic_thumbnail = io.BytesIO(pic.thumbnail.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
    padded_image_array = pad_with_gray_background(
        np.array(Image.open(pic_thumbnail)), 200)

    image_arrays.append(padded_image_array)

Image.fromarray(np.hstack(image_arrays)).show()
```

*note pic.thumbnail is a bytes object taken from the exif*

Comment: Just use slicing... something like `array_padded[0:h, 0:w, :] = _array[:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by Mark Setchell is to use slicing:

```
array_padded[0:height, 0:width, :] = image_array[:]
```

Just have make sure that the shape of image_array is not bigger than array_padded.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image_arrays = []
for pic in pic_selection:
    pic_thumbnail = io.BytesIO(pic.thumbnail.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
    image_array = np.array(Image.open(pic_thumbnail))

    height, width = (200, 200)
    array_padded = np.ones((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)*200
    height = min(image_array.shape[0], height)
    width = min(image_array.shape[1], width)
    array_padded[0:height, 0:width, :] = image_array[0:height, 0:width, :]
    image_arrays.append(array_padded)

Image.fromarray(np.hstack(image_arrays)).show()
```

Comment: Well done and thank you for sharing back with the community. Btw, I think the zero is implicit, so you can omit it `array_padded[:height, :width, :] = image_array[:]`